# What happens when you install Mesa graphics library

Tags: system-installation, graphics, intel-graphics

What happens when you install Mesa graphics drivers on your intel graphics. Does it override the default or it runs the two per priority? 
I'm new to these things so pardon me

Comment: If you are new about that, why do you want to install *Mesa graphics drivers*? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1183770/edit) your answer, you would have better answer about your question/issue

Comment: "Mesa graphics drivers on your intel graphics."  are those intel graphics integrated?!